# Join many SQlite tables - or change data structure

Tags: database, sqlite, join

I am analyzing football game data (coordinates on the pitch x,y,z) stored in an sqlite database.
Each player and the ball have their own sqlite tables, that can be matched via the timestamp

e.g.:

```
table player1: timestamp, x, y, z
table player2: timestamp, x, y, z
table ball: timestamp, x, y, z
```

...

That adds up to 18*2 players (there's a table for each player in the roster, not only for players on pitch) + 1 table for the ball = 39 tables

(1) Would it be more efficent to get the desired coordinates with a huge JOIN chain or the alter the datastructure to have all the data in one "coords" table?

(2) If I can stay with separated tables and JOINS, can I select the tables more easily than joining each of the 39 table manually?

this seems way to complicated for my query:

```
SELECT
  Ballcoords.x AS ballcoords_x,
  Ballcoords.y AS ballcoords_y, 
  Ballcoords.z AS ballcoords_z, 
  Player1.x AS player1_x,
  Player1.y AS player1_y, 
  Player1.z AS player1_z,
  Player2.x AS player2_x,
  Player2.y AS player2_y, 
  Player2.z AS player2_z,
  (... up to Player 38)
FROM 
 Ballcoords 
 LEFT JOIN Player1 ON Ballcoords.timestamp = Player1.timestamp
 LEFT JOIN Player2 ON Ballcoords.timestamp = Player2.timestamp
 (... up to Player 38)
```

Comment: Each player has its own table - NOOOOOOO!!!

Comment: @juergen d so you propose i should have one table containing all the coords instead?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually your going to wonder "Is player near?"

```
Join on cast(playerx/10 as integer) = cast(ballx/10 as integer) and 
cast(playery/10 as integer)  = cast(bally/10 as integer)

if ((integer) playerx/10 = (integer) ballx/10) {
}
```